How to add information in the Power Query column by comparing an ID column
I downloaded this table to study and I have some quesitons. In the "Enrolled" spreadsheet there is the 'Name' column where you can see male and female names, but in the "Complementary Information" spreadsheet there is the Gender column where the data came only as 'Male'. I compared the id of the columns and they are all the same, but somehow the gender column didn't come with the correct information. I was wondering what I should do to add the feminine gender based on the ID and name of the other sheet?


I couldn't find a way to compare it to the id to add the female gender to the column

You don't provide sufficient information. But I suggest you use a similar technique to whatever you used to add the masculine column.

Merge the two columns together choosing the ID field from each table to match, then expand the column that is relevant using the arrows atop the newly created column

you can try merge queries in PQ to get the correct value from another table.
pls see the official docs below.
enter link description here
enter link description here
